# Laravel 5.4 422 (Unprocessable Entity) Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, axios

I am trying to store comments and display the result on the same page with an Ajax call. But I keep getting this error in my console

> 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Let's start with my Comment model:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    // fields can be filled
    protected $fillable = ['body', 'user_id', 'image_request_id'];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the Comment.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Let's continue with my form:

```
{{ Form::open(['id' => 'storeComment', 'route' => ['comments.store'], 'method' => 'POST']) }}
{!! Form::textarea('body', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'rows' => 3]) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('image_request_id', $imageRequest->id) !!}
{{ Form::submit('Add comment', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Let's see out controller method: (CommentController.php)

```
public function store(CommentRequest $request)
{
    $comment = Auth::user()->comments()->save(new Comment($request->all()));

    $response = array(
       'status' => 'success',
       'comment' => $comment
    );

    return response()->json($response);
}
```

My rules method in me CommentRequest.php

```
/**
* Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
*
* @return array
*/
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'body' => 'required|max:1000',
    ];
}
```

Let's see our ajax.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $('#storeComment').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Retrieve form data
            var formData = [];
            var data = $(this).serializeArray();
            $.each(data, function(index, field) {
                formData[field.name] = field.value;
            });

            // Post request with formData as data
            axios.post('/comments', formData).then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
});
```

When I don't use ajax everything workes and the data is being stored.

### EDIT 1 console.log(data) before post request result

```
0: {name: "_token", value: "1DYMMAjNAv9TqOM4ZSu8JRlVpIeImmSDcmXP4Yu7"}
1: {name: "body", value: "blabla"}
2: {name: "image_request_id", value: "2"}
```

### EDIT 2 console.log(formData) result

```
body: "blabla"
image_request_id: "2"
_token: "1DYMMAjNAv9TqOM4ZSu8JRlVpIeImmSDcmXP4Yu7"
```

### EDIT 3 error picture

[screenshot error log in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Cjce.png)

Comment: try to `console.log( data);` before post request

Comment: Place the following line `dd($request->all())` in `function store`, And paste the result here.

Comment: @MayuriPansuriya updated OP

Comment: check the network preview for the error

Comment: it gives a validator error that the "body" field is required, but I do send some data in it as you can see in the log @MayuriPansuriya

Comment: Can you try to rename `body` to something else, like `content` and don't forget to change it inside the view and tell us does that fix it for ya @Michael

Comment: @NikolaGavric same issue :'( renamed everything

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in the wrongly named variable, it is not `temp` but rather `formData`, check the code below:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#storeComment').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Retrieve form data
            var formData = {};
            var data = $(this).serializeArray();
            $.each(data, function(index, field) {
                formData[field.name] = field.value;
            });

            // Post request with temp as data
            axios.post('/comments', formData).then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
   });
```

Comment: No same issue, just an error with copy pasting I update OP

Comment: Could you also do a `console.log(formData)` and put that in the question?

Comment: Updated OP with the console.log(formData)

Comment: Btw idk if you seen, but you have double `submit` handlers in your `ajax.js` file

Comment: That's just an error with copy/paste sorry, i updated OP

Comment: Can you remove the comment from the response array inside your controller and try it?

Comment: Can you try `console.log([formData]);` and give us a picture or update your question with result from it?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the console when logging [formData]

Comment: @Michael try to change `var formData = [];` to `var formData = {};`